# add zipcode form on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2

I am currently to add a new tab just above add to cart button that will check the pin-code option but i failed to achieve this here is my code:-

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Learn\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\View\CheckDelivery" name="textblock" as="textblock" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/zipcode.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

**vendor/module/Block/product/view/CheckDelivery.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learn\Module\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CheckDelivery extends Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

**vendor/module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/zipcode.phtml**

```
<?php?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<h3><?php echo 'My Product Name Is: ' . $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
```

but this not displaying on frontend PDP any help on this

Comment: What error you're getting ? Or can you please tell me what is the path of this file ? **catalog_product_view.xml**

Comment: vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and am not getting any error rather it not visible on frotnend

Comment: Please check my answer @Pramod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update this code in your `catalog_product_view.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Learn/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Learn\Module\Block\Product\View\CheckDelivery" name="textblock" as="textblock" after="-" template="Learn_Module::catalog/product/view/zipcode.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please check your Block file's path is correct in above `XML` file's block class. There you've added `Learn\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\View\CheckDelivery` and you've created that block file here `Learn\Module\Block\Product\View\CheckDelivery`. So please correct that and add your Block file here..

> app/code/Learn/Module/Block/Product/View/CheckDelivery.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Learn\Module\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CheckDelivery extends Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

Now add your `phtml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Learn/Module/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/zipcode.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php $_product = $block->getCurrentProduct() ?>
<h3><?php echo 'My Product Name Is: ' . $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
```

In above file you've called `$block->getProduct()` this function and you've to call this one `$block->getCurrentProduct()`, because you've created `getCurrentProduct()` function in custom block file.

**Output** :

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: tell me one thing i dnt helper for this thing to be displayed on frontend right??

Comment: Means, what you're asking I do not understand.

Comment: thank a lot the path was incorrect i didnt saw that

Comment: You're welcome Buddy :) You can accept answer if it helps. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can review [GitHub](https://github.com/vrajeshkpatel/v4u-magento2-check-delivery-availability) module for Product available on specific zipcode.

Comment: that would be complex i wana make my own for he better understanding

Comment: Ok. On github is the module I have tried yesterday. You can also try.

Comment: can u provide me the link

Comment: I have already provided in my answer.